# Omit return type from a function type?

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

Is it possible to create a new function type from an existing typescript function that has the same parameters and generics but without the return type?

**Example:**

I am trying to create the type `ReturnNothing` from the `ReturnSame` function without having to define it manually.

```js
type ReturnSame = <T extends string>(a: T) => T
type ReturnNothing = <T extends string>(a: T) => void
```

**Attempts:**

```js
function returnSame<T extends string>(a: T): T {
  return a;
}

// Attempt 1: Does not work. Generics is not following to new type.
const returnNothing1 = (...params: Parameters<typeof returnSame>) => {
  console.log(params);
};

// Attempt 2: Does not work. Return type is forced.
const returnNothing2: typeof returnSame = (...params) => {
  console.log(params);
};

// Attempt 3: Does not work. OmitReturn is a made up Typescript utility.
const returnNothing3: OmitReturn<typeof returnSame> = (...params) => {
  console.log(params);
};

// Usage
const same = returnSame<"a">("a");
const nothing1 = returnNothing1<"b">("b");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's currently no way to do this automatically *purely* at the type level.  Meaning: you can't take a generic function type like `ReturnSame` and grab its parameters in a way that doesn't immediately plug in `unknown` (or whatever its generic constraint is) for its type parameter(s) like `T`.  Doing this would probably require *higher kinded types* which TypeScript does not currently support directly (see [microsoft/TypeScript#1213](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1213) for the feature request).

You *could* give up completely and write out `returnNothing()` manually as a generic function, but you don't want to do that.

If it's acceptable to drop down to the value level, by passing `returnSame()` to a function, you can leverage [higher order type inference from generic functions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#higher-order-type-inference-from-generic-functions) as introduced in TypeScript 3.4:

```
function makeNothingReturner<A extends any[]>(fn: (...a: A) => any): (...a: A) => void {
  return (...a) => void fn(...a);
}

const returnNothing = makeNothingReturner(returnSame);
```

Here `makeNothingReturner()` takes a (possibly generic) function and returns another function with the same parameters with a `void` return type.  The type signature for this *looks* very much like what you were doing in your type-level code, so it might be surprising that this would not do the same thing and have `returnNothing` be of type `(...args: unknown) => void`.  But behold, IntelliSense shows this:

```
// const returnNothing: <T extends string>(a: T) => void
```

and thus you can use it as desired, by calling with a specified type parameter:

```
const nothing = returnNothing<"b">("b"); // works
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAJwKZRMsBlAhgW1QB4AVRVADylTABMBnReqZGMAcwD4AKXALkQkAlALIBvAFCIU6TElwBuCQF8JE0JFgJE+XAGtUAOThQAFm3YAlWVlTIiAQXJUaDRLjABPANoBdHsBgAtwAdGH8iA5CiAC8nO5eIoih4QJRsfEAbnAwtIiS0mgYWMlhIbjRcYjZuYiBKeVCSqoSEAjMMsVgxmYWsTr6RibmHNZddtxFcniETRIA9POIbWAdU1g9I+wCpM7UdIzMrBw8EcIZ1Tm0aouIAKr0uOyore1QiGDDFgCM-evdXw4RAARAAjYE8MHAuZAA)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what @jcalz said: It's partially possible at the type level. ([Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA4hB2AxAcgHgMoBooBUB8UAvFKgILpQQAewCAJgM5Tp4AUAhgFxTkCURBHACgRoSFABqAewCWdFKhiUa9JnCRp28ENi0g8BQkKixlteI1gIFM%20ADMIAJ2a7teYyagB%20KxozYAN1k6d08obngIAKcRITFoHAALGQYAdSlHAGsmYmk5BXUFAEZsACYDWPjcZIYAESkIBmQpYHSsoklghTIKanNLIrYuHnR%20QgJyoSA))

```
type GenFN<S, T> = <AS extends S>(a: AS) => T


type VoidFN<G extends GenFN<any, any>> =
  G extends GenFN<infer S, any>
    ? GenFN<S, void>
    : never


type ThisWorks = VoidFN<GenFN<1, 2>>


type ThisDoesNotWork = VoidFN<<AS extends 1>(a: AS) => 2>
```

But this would require you to use the helper `GenFN` everywhere instead of direct definitions like `<AS extends 1>(a: AS) => 2`, rendering `VoidFN` incompatible with parts of your (current and future) codebase and third party libraries.

Another risk: I am not sure if TS could maybe "forget"/"discard" the information that a specific type extends `GenFN` due to internal optimiziations should your codebase become large and the type definitions deeply nested.